# split pyspark dataframe column in multiple dynamic column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have dataframe with 1000 of column from which i want to split 600 columns with delimiter and create new column for each.
ex. "a|b|c|d"
then it will create 4 new column in dataframe.

I have done some code but is is too slow.

## this will get called to split column and return new dataframe passing column list and dataframe to apply function

```py
def split_columns_in_pipe(columns,hitDF):
    try:
        for col_name in columns:
            split_col = split(col(col_name), "\\|")
            new_column_name = col_name + '_split'
            hitDF = hitDF.withColumn(new_column_name, split_col)
            column_size = hitDF.select(max(size(hitDF[new_column_name]))).collect()[0][0]
            print(col_name,column_size)
            hitDF = hitDF.drop(new_column_name)
            if column_size > 1:
                for i in range(column_size):
                    split_column_name = "{}_{}".format(col_name, i + 1)
                    hitDF = hitDF.withColumn(split_column_name, split_col.getItem(i))
                hitDF.drop(col_name)
        return hitDF
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception spliting column-{}".format(str(ex)))




hitDF = split_columns_in_pipe(columns_list,hitDF)
```

Please help me to achieve this in minimum time.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this? your question is not much clear

Comment: I want to split single column in multiple column based on column value with delimiter  for ex. my column contains value "a|b|c|d" the i want to add 4 new column to my existing dataframe value of column may differ from column to column.